# Android Studio: Accessing ListView inside a Fragment (2nd layout pass error)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am creating an app with many fragments but It throws an error when I try to access my ListView inside Fragment. I tested this code piece before in MainActivity and it worked fine.

Here is the fragment code :

```
public class Theme extends Fragment {

CustomAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_layout, container, false);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference();

    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    return v;
}




private ArrayList getData() {
    final ArrayList<Teemad> teemadelist = new ArrayList<>();

    myRef.child("teemad").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for(DataSnapshot child: children){
                Teemad teemad = child.getValue(Teemad.class);
                teemadelist.add(teemad);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return teemadelist;

}
}
```

This is my layout file:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/container">
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

And these are two of the main errors (at least I assume so) it throws:

```
03-23 01:14:50.296 9127-9127/com.example.richard.kodutoo_messenger W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2ffc0764 V.ED.... ......ID 16,123-227,180 #7f0d0087 app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
03-23 01:14:50.455 9127-9127/com.example.richard.kodutoo_messenger W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Any kind of help or feedback would come in handy since I have been stuck at this place for a very long time. If additional information is needed to answer, then I will gladly provide it.

EDIT!!

I tried to use ListFragment instead of Fragment and after onCreateView I used onActivityCreated but it came out even worse.. Before it at least started the app, now the app crashes as soon as it starts.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference();

    lv = (ListView) getListView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: do you use android.support.v7.widget.ListView;
you may just use import android.widget.ListView;

Comment: You should know that you beyond any issues you have now, you're going to have an issue with `getData()`, as you have a callback in that method and it will return an empty `ArrayList`, rather than a completed one.

Comment: @Elsunhoty Im using import android.widget.ListView so that cannot be the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are using your adapter in combination with firebase events.

The right order would be something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_layout, container, false);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference();

    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity()); // Note : Here no passing of data
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    startListener();

    return v;
}

public void startListener() {
    myRef.child("teemad").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<Teemad> teemadelist = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

        for(DataSnapshot child: children){
            Teemad teemad = child.getValue(Teemad.class);
            teemadelist.add(teemad);
        }

        adapter.items = teemadelist; // Here items is a public field in adapter holding list of items
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but inside Adapter class there are methods getCount and getItem which need the 'items' array but since the array is empty it throws and error. What should i do in that case?

Comment: Initialize that array by default to an empty array. I tend to use an ArrayList -> public List<Teemad> items = new ArrayList(); as property in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

The RequestLayout error was happening to me too. It would crash my App or throw an Exception but it would show up in the Log as if to warm me.

I solved it by putting the code where I was setting different margins for the ListView into a Runnable and call the Runnable with a Handler and no more warning/error.

I have come to believe that specific error most likely has to do with trying to adjust/change/redraw the ListView or some child Views belonging to the ListView 
without using a Runnable.

I prefer to post the Runnable to a Handler anytime now when I change a View's or ViewGroup's attributes at runtime.